# Java equivalent to pyftpdlib?

Tags: java, python, ftp

Is there a good Java alternative to pyftpdlib? I am looking for an easy to setup and run embedded ftp server.

Comment: removed embedded tag used for embedded/real-time related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Apache's [FTPServer](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/).

They have an [example](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/embedding-ftpserver-in-5-minutes.html) of how to embed it in a Java application.